# preg_match is only matching single occurrence

Tags: php, regex

I have a `preg_match` that's only matching one occurrence

```
preg_match('/(\$[0-9,]+(\.[0-9]{2})?)/', $lines[0], $match);
```

Here is the data:

```
<strong>Apr- May Price: </strong>Adult: $2,999.00 Children: $2,249.00 <br />
```

When I do a `print_r` on `$match` I get the following

```
Array ( [0] => $2,999.00 [1] => $2,999.00 [2] => .00 )
```

I should be getting `$2,999.00` and `$2,249.00` stored in the `$match`

Comment: *"preg match is only matching single occurnace"*: indeed, the function is designed to do that.

Comment: @Casimir thank you, I figured that until I looked at preg_match_all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) instead.

```
$string = '<strong>Apr- May Price: </strong>Adult: $2,999.00 Children: $2,249.00 <br />';
preg_match_all('/(\$[0-9,]+(\.[0-9]{2})?)/', $string, $match);
```

And the result of a `var_dump($match);`:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "$2,999.00"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "$2,249.00"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "$2,999.00"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "$2,249.00"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) ".00"
    [1]=>
    string(3) ".00"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This solves the issue and I'll accept your answer.